# How do I re-express a list comprehension with two generators to two list comprehensions with one generator each and get the same result?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm trying to learn Haskell, and I'm doing some exercises that involves lists. But I'm struggling with an exercise about list comprehension, and I really need someone to help me with this. The exercise reads:

*Show how the list comprehension `[(x,y) | x <- [1,2], y <- [3,4]]` with two generators
can be re-expressed using two comprehensions with single generators.*

*Hint: nest one comprehension within the other and make use of the library function `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`.*

I appreciate all answers and explanations.
Thanks.

Comment: So, what part of that hint is unclear?

Comment: I simply don't know how to do it or what it means.

Comment: Well, there are only so many ways you can nest one list comprehension in another, why don't you try some of them?

Comment: I don't even understand what that means. The only way i can think of is by doing this:                                                       

`zip [x | x <- [1,1,2,2]] [y | y <- [3,4,3,4]]`

But that's probably cheating since i'm customizing the lists in the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can generate `[1, 2]` using `[x | x <- [1, 2]]`.

Now, for each `x`, you want to have `(x, 3)` and `(x, 4)` instead of just `x`. So let's replace it with a list comprehension. Then you'll get `[[(x, y) | y <- [3, 4]] | x <- [1, 2]]`.

But this gives you `[[(1,3),(1,4)],[(2,3),(2,4)]]` because you converted each `x` to `[(x, 3), (x, 4)]`. As the hint suggests, you can use `concat` to squash them.

To put it together, you'll get `concat [[(x, y) | y <- [3, 4]] | x <- [1, 2]]`.